# A way to print with memory address in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Is there a way to include the memory address whenever printing something in gdb. For example:

```
>>> p __libc_argc
$4 = 1
```

Instead, I'd like to have:

```
>>> p __libc_argc
$4 = 0x7fffffffec63  1
```

Comment: You could just print `&__libc_argc` first

Comment: @Barmar that works, thanks. `>>> x/d &__libc_argc` `0x7ffff7fc0e78 <__libc_argc>: 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the memory address of a variable just add `&` before its name. If you often want to print both the variable address and its value it might be worth creating a command for that. For instance, add the code below to your `.gdbinit` file

```
define pwa
  print &$arg0
  print $arg0
end
```

With this, you will have a `pwa` command (short for "print with address") that you can use instead of the standard `print` command whenever you want both the address and the value to be printed.